# Jquery .serialize isn't including the FIRST SET at INDEX 0

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

My jquery looks like this:

```
var as = $("input[name=as[]]").serialize();
var bs = $("input[name=bs[]]").serialize();
var cs = $("input[name=cs[]]").serialize();
```

but it's not serializing the first set at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple workaround, you might consider giving the blank fields a token or placeholder value prior to serializing, which you can test for on the server, for example:

```
$('form > :input:empty').val('Token String To Indicate Emptiness');
alert($('form').serialize());
```